# Relation between $CA^kB$ and $C(sI-A)^{-1}B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{q\times n}$. In addition, let $\bar A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $\bar B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, and $\bar C\in\mathbb{R}^{q\times n}$. Prove or disprove that

\begin{equation}
CA^kB=\bar C\bar A^k \bar B {\rm ~~for~all~~} k=0,2,...,n-1 \iff C(sI-A)^{-1}B=\bar C(sI-\bar A)^{-1}\bar B, {\rm ~~where~~} s\in\mathbb{C}
\end{equation}

---

To show $C(sI-A)^{-1}B=\bar C(sI-\bar A)^{-1}\bar B$ implies $CA^kB=\bar C\bar A^k \bar B$, I think we can use inverse Laplace transform:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}[C(sI-A)^{-1}B=\bar C(sI-\bar A)^{-1}\bar B]
\end{align}
yields $Ce^{tA}B=\bar Ce^{t\bar A}\bar B$, which implies at $t=0$, $CB=\bar C\bar B$. Also, taking $\frac{d^k}{dt^k}$ of $Ce^{tA}B=\bar Ce^{t\bar A}\bar B$ at $t=0$, yields $CA^kB=\bar C\bar A^k \bar B$.

I do not know how to prove/disprove the other direction of $\iff$.

Comment: Presumably you mean $(sI-A)^{-1}$, etc, above?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Please see edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for Laplace transform. Just note that the power series expansion of an analytic $f$ is unique.

Note that for $|s| > \|A\|$ we have
$(sI-A)^{-1} = {1 \over s} (I+{A \over s} + {A^2 \over s^2} +\cdots)$.

Alternatively (equivalently, really), note that $Ce^{At}B = \sum_k t^kC A^k B$.

Comment: Thanks. What if $|s|\geq \|A\|$?

Comment: Let $f,g$ be the two transfer functions above, $f$ is analytic except on $\sigma(A)$ and $g$ is analytic except on $\sigma(\bar{A})$. The above shows that $f(s)=g(s)$ for $|s| > \max(\|A\|,\|\bar{A}\|)$. Since both domains are connected we have $f(s)=g(s)$ everywhere that $f$ & $g$ are defined.

Comment: Aarg, I messed up by inequalities everywhere. You need $\|{A \over s}\| < 1 $.